# How to plot dynamic rolling mean?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

For example, I've a table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-19 10:47:18 | 2021-10-19 10:47:20 | 00:00:02 |
| 2021-10-19 10:47:21 | 2021-10-19 10:47:22 | 00:00:01 |
| 2021-10-19 10:47:25 | 2021-10-19 10:47:25 | 00:00:00 |
| 2021-10-19 10:47:27 | 2021-10-19 10:47:27 | 00:00:00 |
| 2021-10-19 10:47:28 | 2021-10-19 10:47:30 | 00:00:03 |

I want to plot a graph where on x-axis I've datetime, and on y-axis rolling mean of column C. So, that I want to know how mean value of difference between column A and B are changed over time.

Thus, plot should look like: at 2021-10-19 10:47:20 - mean is  2, at 2021-10-19 10:47:22 it is 1.5 etc. Or even at 1 hour time interval.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set column B as your index (assuming your DataFrame is called df):

```
df.set_index('B', inplace=True)
```

Than add to the dataframe a new column with rolling mean on column C:

```
df['Rolling mean'] = df['C'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=1)
```

I chose the mean to be calculated for a rolling window of 5 rows (you can change that)

Reset index to get initial dataframe with new column

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I have 'NotImplementedError': See issue #11704 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704

Comment: What is the complete error you get?